# Minimum True Monotone 3SAT

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, sat

I am interested in a SAT variation where the CNF formula is monotone (no variables are negated). Such a formula is obviously satisfiable.

But say the number of true variables is a measure of how good our solution is.  So we have the following problem:

MINIMUM TRUE MONOTONE 3SAT

INSTANCE: Set U of variables, collection C of disjunctive clauses of 3 literals, where a literal is a variable (not negated).
SOLUTION: A truth assignment for U that satisfies C.
MEASURE:  The number of variable that are true.

Could someone give me some helpful remarks on this problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This problem is the same as the Vertex Cover problem for $3$-uniform hypergraphs: 
given a collection $H$ of subsets of $V$ of size $3$ each, find a minimal subset $U\subseteq V$ that intersects each set in $H$.

It is therefore NP-hard, but fixed parameter tractable. 
It is also NP-hard to approximate to within a factor of $2-\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$. This was shown in the following paper:

Irit Dinur, Venkatesan Guruswami, Subhash Khot and Oded Regev.
[A New Multilayered PCP and the Hardness of Hypergraph Vertex Cover](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~dinuri/mypapers/hvc-DGKR.pdf),
SIAM Journal on Computing, 34(5):1129–1146, 2005.

Comment: Another keyword would be "3-Hitting Set." I don't have access to the following paper now, but the title seems relevant: http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?hl=en&q=An+efficient+fixed-parameter+algorithm+for+3-Hitting+Set

Comment: The approximation threshold is actually $3 - \epsilon$.

Comment: @MCH: Reference?

Comment: @Radu GRIGore:  i believe the link you give is the FPT algorithm mentioned in the answer by Jan Johannsen.  thanks for the help you two.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: the reference for 3−ϵ is the paper given by Jan.

Comment: No, its $2-\epsilon$: for $k$-uniform hypergraph vertex cover, they show hardness of approximation to within $(k-1-\epsilon)$.

Comment: The paper linked by Radu indeed gives a fixed parameter algorithm for 3-Hitting Set, aka 3-uniform hypergraph vertex cover. An improved algorithm was given in the following paper, for which I don't have a link right now:

H. Fernau. A top-down approach to search-trees: improved algorithmics for 3-Hitting Set. Algorithmica, 57:97–18, 2010.

Comment: oops... @MCH: i'm interested to see the $3 - \epsilon$ result as well.  it would imply that the trivial approximation algorithm is the best we can hope for.

Answer (score 7):

I would start by having a look at papers citing [Downey and Fellows' paper](http://mrfellows.net/papers/DF95_FPTandCompletenessI.pdf), in which they consider the following problem and prove its $W[1]$-completeness.

**WEIGHTED $q$-CNF SAT**

**Instance:** A CNF formula $X$ (i.e., a formula in Conjunctive
Normal Form) in which every clause contains $q$ variables.

**Parameter:** A positive integer $k$.

**Question:** Does X have a satisfying assignment of weight $k$, where the weight of an assignment is the number of variables it sets to "true"?